# Showing only actual column data in SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm spooling out delimited text files from SQL*Plus, but every column is printed as the full size per its definition, rather than the data actually in that row.

For instance, a column defined as 10 characters, with a row value of "test", is printing out as "test      " instead of "test". I can confirm this by selecting the column along with the value of its LENGTH function. It prints "test      |4".

It kind of defeats the purpose of a delimiter if it forces me into fixed-width. Is there a SET option that will fix this, or some other way to make it print only the actual column data.

I don't want to add TRIM to every column, because if a value is actually *stored* with spaces I want to be able to keep them.

Thanks

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/14141967/124416

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen many SQL*plus script, that create text files like this:

```
select A || ';' || B || ';' || C || ';' || D
from T
where ...
```

It's a strong indication to me that you can't just switch to variable length output with a *SET* command.

Instead of ';' you can of course use any other delimiter. And it's up to your query to properly escape any characters that could be confused with a delimiter or a line feed.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that. We'll probably just end up using TRIM on all the columns and hope that we aren't ever asked to research how common trailing spaces are.

It just seems weird to me that they would offer built-in delimited output, without the ability to turn off fixed-width. Why would you want both?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I'd forget SQL Plus as a method for getting CSV out of Oracle.

Tom Kyte has written a nice little Pro-C [unloader](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:459020243348)

Personally I've written a utility which does similar but in perl